# Plotting 2 vectors in one graph with factor vector as x-axis

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot 2 integer[] vectors:*a,b* onto a factor[] vector:*c*, using the following code:

```
plot(c,a,type='l',col="blue",xlab="foo",ylab="bar")
lines(c,b,col="red")
```

Vector c contains strings such as: "2007-09-30 - 2007-10-06".

I am facing two problems using this method:

1. The first call plots the vector as points, even though I have specified `type='l'` and ignores the argument `col="blue"`.
2. Vector c is rather large and R is trying to fit every element as a discrete point on the x-axis, which is rather hideous.

The rendered output looks like this:
[image]

Does anyone have suggestions on how to fix my problems?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: convert your `factor`, `c` to a `Date` class, at least for plotting. see `?Date`

Comment: You, Sir, are a genius! :) Fixes every single problem I was having :D

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't accept your comment :(

Comment: @timriffe If you posted your comment as an answer I could accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, no time for an example right now, but here's my feeble advice:

convert your `factor`, `c` to a `Date` class, at least for plotting. see `?Date`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ggplot2` and use the `date` class rather than a `factor`:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(c=as.Date("2007-06-13")+0:1399, a=rnorm(1400,30,8), b=rnorm(1400,60,10))
ggplot(dat) + geom_path(aes(x=c,y=a),col=I("red")) + geom_path(aes(x=c,y=b),col=I("blue"))
```

Or better still if you put your data is in long format:

```
datLong <- melt(dat,id="c")
qplot(c,value,data=datLong,geom="path",colour=variable)
```

[image: plot]